# TypeError: function takes at most 4 arguments (6 given)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I am making a particle simulator in python 2.7 with the Pygame module. And i'm getting an error with involving some classes, that I cant fix, please help. Here is code:

```
 import pygame, sys
 from colors import *
 from random import randint
 import particles

 pygame.init()

 #background = pygame.image.load("graphics//background.jpg")
 #Background = pygame.Surface(background.get_size(), pygame.HWSURFACE)
 #Background.blit(background, (0, 0))


 global window, window_height, window_width, window_title
 window_width, window_height = 800, 600
 window_title = "particle game"
 title_icon = "graphics//icons//icon_title.jpg"
 pygame.display.set_caption(window_title)
 window = pygame.display.set_mode((window_width, 
 window_height), pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF)


 particle_size = 2


 class Particle(object):
      def __init__(self, Color, xpos, ypos):
          pygame.draw.rect(window, Color, xpos, ypos, particle_size, particle_size)



 class Hydrogen(Particle):
      def __init__(self, Color, xpos, ypos):
          Particle.__init__(self, Color, xpos, ypos)
          pygame.draw.rect(window, Color, xpos, ypos, particle_size, particle_size)

          window.fill(Color.LightGray)

          particle_num = 12
          isRunning = True
          #for particle in range(particle_num):
               #Hydrogen(Color.Green)
               #print"hello"
 while isRunning:

     for event in pygame.event.get():
          if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
              isRunning = False
          elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
              mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
              Hydrogen(Color.Orange, mx, my)

 pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Indentation is correct, indentation was probably messed up when copied.

**Here are all the errrors:**

> ```
> line 53, in <module>
>       Hydrogen(Color.Orange, mx, my)
>
> line 36, in __init__
>       Particle.__init__(self, Color, xpos, ypos)
>
> line 30, in __init__
>       pygame.draw.rect(window, Color, xpos, ypos, particle_size, particle_size)
> TypeError: function takes at most 4 arguments (6 given)
> ```

Comment: I know hardly anything of PyGame, but I think it should be `pygame.draw.rect(window, Color, (xpos, ypos, particle_size, particle_size))`

Comment: please fix code indentations.

Comment: "Indentation is correct, indentation was probably messed up when copied" doesn't help. If I wanted to run your code to debug your problem, my interpreter is going to give me an `IndentationError` or silently do the wrong thing. I can't just say, "Sorry, Python, Tarantula guy says it's right on his machine, so please run it anyway".

Comment: The error is quite clear, and the way forward is to read the doc for the function you are incorrectly using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `rect` takes only 4 arguments but you are passing it 6 arguments and that's why you get the error. Here is the documentation:

```
pygame.draw.rect()
draw a rectangle shape
rect(Surface, color, Rect, width=0) -> Rect
Draws a rectangular shape on the Surface. The given Rect is the area of the rectangle. The width argument is the thickness to draw the outer edge. If width is zero then the rectangle will be filled.

Keep in mind the Surface.fill() method works just as well for drawing filled rectangles. In fact the Surface.fill() can be hardware accelerated on some platforms with both software and hardware display modes.
```

as you can see, it takes only `Surface`, `color`, `Rect` and `width` which has a default of 0. You are passing 6 by doing `pygame.draw.rect(window, Color, xpos, ypos, particle_size, particle_size)`. You need to pass in `pygame.Rect(xpos, ypos, particle_size, particle_size)` as the third parameter and delete all other parameters except `window` and `Color`. So it should look like this:

`pygame.draw.rect(window, Color, pygame.Rect(xpos, ypos, particle_size, particle_size)`

Comment: @Tarantulaguy please accept the answer if it helped (there is a white check mark next to my answer). thanks mate :)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect), the last argument should be a `Rectangle` object.

In your `Particle` constructor, change the first line to this:

```
class Particle(object):
    def __init__(self, Color, xpos, ypos):
        pygame.draw.rect(window, Color, pygame.Rect(xpos, ypos, particle_size, particle_size))
```